# Uploading pdf file with cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

I need to create automatic test that as part of the flow i need to upload pdf file in my main application.

But i didnt find a way to do that...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading file works in Cypress when target "input" element is of "type="file"

```
    cy.get("#myFile").selectFile("cypress/fixtures/dummy.pdf")
```

[image]

where ID of the input of type file= #myFile" and path of pdf file="cypress/fixtures/dummy.pdf"

Please refer to Cypress Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile